# Searching nodes in graphs Graphs

Tags: algorithm, math, search, graph, graph-theory

Suppose you have a Directed Acyclic Graph. There are 2 kinds of nodes in this graph `Normal` and `Error` nodes. Nodes have a dependence like this:

Before you check a node if it's an error you have some probabilistic information on that node. Each node tells you: I dont know if I am an error node but I might be an error node if the next one is. And for every edge you have conditional probabilities relating the 2 nodes.

> For every (A)--->(B)  you have probability P(A|B) which represents the probability of A being an error node if B is error.

You can only check a number of nodes `N` in the graph. The total number of nodes in the graph is larger than `N`.

What would be a good algorithm to look for nodes in this graph in a way that if there is an `error` node in the graph you will most likely find it?

> The informal problem is like this: You have some products and you want
>   to check them if they're broken. But in order to check you spend
>   money. You have a limited amount of money. The point is that with the
>   budget you have for checking, if you find a broken product in the pack
>   you buy none and you go do business elsewhere. What's the best way you
>   can spend the money to increase your probabilty of finding a broken
>   product if there is one?  I'm supposing you can also represent the
>   problem as linear programming. What could be some other ways of
>   representing the problem  and how would you solve it ?

Comment: If you do not have any further data to go with, it is going to be very difficult. Is there any statistical bias? At least a distribution? A metric of product quality? If the latter, watch this [Numerophile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWib5olGbQ0). Is your tree structure even relevant? Do `Error` Nodes have more `Error` children?

Comment: Is the DAG part relevant in any way? E.g., is there a rule that a descendant of a faulty node is faulty as well?

Comment: Error nodes do have error children and the problem can become reduced to the hidden dense subgraph problem but I don't think that's solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes. You have probabilities.  Current node might be e lemon if the next node is a lemon. And so on.

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: No, my homework is something else, related. This is something that I was thinking by myself. Different ways to formalize problems in real life...@duffymo

Comment: You really should edit the relevance of the graph into the question.

Comment: @MvG No, because in my context it is very important that I use graphs. I left the solution space open just to see how other people think if the graph was not obligatory.

Comment: @MarcusAurelius: I think you misunderstood me. In a comment you wrote that error nodes will have error children. This fact belongs into your question. Otherwise it's completely unclear why you are speaking about a graph, instead of just a bunch of unrelated objects. So please edit that in. Be precise whether they have *only* error children, or just *more likely* error children. Also provide any other information that might be connected to the graph structure.

Comment: @MvG You are right. I am going to edit that right away.

Comment: @MvG I just finished editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment stating that error nodes will have (only) error children, one simplification will be to concentrate on leaf nodes: if any inner node is an error node, then there must be at least one leaf node which is an error as well.

If the number of leafs exceeds *N* as well, then you have to choose which leafs to test. You want to maximize the total number of nodes covered by these leafs. I.e. find a set of *N* leafs which maximizes the number of ancestors these have.

A greedy strategy would compute the number of ancestors for every leaf, then choose one with maxial number of ancestors and recompute ancestor counts for all the others. A brute force strategy would try all combinations of choosing *N* leafs.

A model which resembles linear programming might have one binary (i.e. {0,1}) variable per leaf. 0 would mean choosing it, while 1 would mean not choosing it, so you'd have an equation stating that the sum over all these leafs is equal to the number of leafs minus *N*. The objective function would be a sum with one summand per inner node. The term for each of them would be the product of the variables for the leafs descendent from it. So the value for each inner node would be 1 if all leafs are 1 but 0 if there is at least one leaf which is 0. Minimize the sum of these and you have maximized the number of covered inner nodes. The objective is obviously highly non-linear, so it's not linear programming, nor even binary integer programming.

If the number *N* is very large or very small compared to the number of leafs, you might approximate an optimal solutiono by assuming some independence. If you can select almost all leafs, you can look for those leafs which have fewest inner nodes that lead to no other leaf. Perhaps removing the dropped portion from the tree after every such step. If you can select almost no leafs, the greedy strategy above would let you select those which maximal number of ancestors. In both these cases you might assume that your individual choices don't interact with one another too much, justifying the greedy approach.